# Is there any algorithms to select orders of ARIMA wihtout using ACF/PACF and trial and error method(HK algorithm)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I just need to figure out a way in which the seasonal ARIMA orders should be selected for a data without using ACF/PACF plot...

I have tried ACF/PACF plot based approach and also Hyndman-Khandhakar Algorithm which is some sort of trial and error method based on AICc. The results are not promising... May need a algorithm or a way in which order can be selected...